# Eu especifico o ícone que eu desejo aplicar no meu botão com bootstrap, mas ele só aparece vazio na página... O que está havendo?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, django

```
<div>
    <span>TROCO</span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse" id="collapse">
        <div class="card card-body">
            texto
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esse aí é o trecho que tem o botão. O ícone simplesmente não aparece...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qual versão do bootstrap você esta usando? a versão 4 não tem mais glyphicon.
ao inves utilize https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0   fontawesome esta na versão 6 mais a 4.7 é muito boa.
se for a 3 pode fazer assim

Comment: poxa cara valeu!